# How can I replace an <object...> with the actual content of that object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Lets say I have this:

```
<object class="MyClass" type="text/html" data="/Whatever/1?renderpartial=1"></object>
<object class="MyClass" type="text/html" data="/Whatever/2?renderpartial=1"></object>
```

And, I want to use jQuery to replace the object with the actual HTML of the object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".MyClass").before('<div class="MyClass">#CONTENT#</div>').remove();
    });
</script>
```

I want to fire off an asynchronous request to go get each of '/Whatever/1' and '/Whatever/2' from the server and put it in place of '#CONTENT#'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the original object as a div:

```
$(function(){
    $('.MyClass').each(function(){
        var $current = $(this);
        $.post($current.attr('data'), function(data){
            $current.replaceWith('<div>' + data + '</div>');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, that mostly works, but there seems to be a bug in my version of jquery that is preventing the replaceWith from executing properly...  The HTML is being fetched just fine tho...  The error is `Error: (this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment is not a function`

Comment: Ok, that was a scope error on my part. I updated my example, so try it once more using the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [jquery load function](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback):

```
$(".MyClass").each(function(){
  $(this).replace("<div>").load($(this).attr("data"));
});
```

Comment: +1: Ok, that looks pretty good, but I want to turn the OBJECT into a DIV and `load` the DIV with the URL of the original object.  Can that be done cleanly?